# Calling Generic-HttpHandler inside another Generic-HttpHandler

Tags: asp.net, httphandler

I want to call a `genric http-handler` inside another `generic-http-handler` **Inside the same project**.
Suppose I have to two handlers

1. FirstHanlder.ashx
2. SecondHandler.ashx

I want to call the second on `SecondHandler.ashx` on the `FirstHandler.ashx`
I created an instance of `SecondHandler.ashx` on the `FirstHandler.ashx` as follows

```
var objCreateLogs=new SecondHandler();
objCreateLogs.ProcessRequest(context);
```

I want to know will it work?

<del>1. Further more do I need to pass the `**context**` or it will be implicitly there.</del>

1. How Can I get response of the `SecondHandler.ashx` on the `FirstHandler.ashx` since the return type of `ProcessRequest` is void.
2. Can I get response from `httpcontex`

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

The handlers should not do the work. Create a Class/Method that does the word and use it in both handlers.

```
//Extract parameters    
string par1=Request["a"];
//...
//Call a backend function
var result = MyFunctions.DoTheWork(par1);
```

Comment: It's is working for me. The handler it self is a class and can be called from anywhere in the application. But I am concern about the response which I will get from the handler.

Comment: You should use another class and in the Method specify a proper return type. If you don't need further processin you can also try Context.Server.Transfer()

Comment: I have all ready existing code and if I create new one I will have to make changes in the the codes.